# Generate a member name using preprocessor directives?

Tags: c++, c, preprocessor-directive

I would like to achieve the following but I can't get it right:

```
struct SamplerState
{
    int i;
};

#define SAMPLER_TYPE Point
#define SAMPLER_MODE_U ClampU
#define SAMPLER_MODE_V ClampV
#define SAMPLER_NAME( a, b, c ) ( ##a ##_ ##b ##_ ##c)
#define SAMPLER SamplerState SAMPLER_NAME(SAMPLER_TYPE, SAMPLER_MODE_U, SAMPLER_MODE_V)

int main()
{
    SAMPLER = {};
}
```

I expect the name of `SAMPLER` to be `Point_ClampU_ClampV` but it isn't when debugging, it is `SAMPLER_TYPE_SAMPLER_MODE_U_SAMPLER_MODE_V` instead:

[image]

**Question:**

How can I achieve that, if possible at all?

Comment: Doesn't something like `(#a "_" #b "_" #c)` do the trick?

Comment: @Nederes One hash: stringize, two hash: token-pasting. And, string literals cannot be identifiers.

Comment: What is the need to do such hacks? Even if you *can* do it, you shouldn't!

Comment: Well, long story short, in a shader you can't use more than 16 samplers, so with this, I am able to dynamically generate the right one according some defines which are set by toggles in UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can't join `(` with `a` in `(##a`. No need to tho.
2. You have to have another level of expansion, another macro, to let `a`, `b` and `c` expand.

```
struct SamplerState
{
    int i;
};


#define SAMPLER_TYPE Point
#define SAMPLER_MODE_U ClampU
#define SAMPLER_MODE_V ClampV
#define SAMPLER_NAME_IN(a, b, c)  ( a##_ ##b##_##c )
#define SAMPLER_NAME(a, b, c)  SAMPLER_NAME_IN(a, b, c)
#define SAMPLER SamplerState SAMPLER_NAME(SAMPLER_TYPE, SAMPLER_MODE_U, SAMPLER_MODE_V)

int main()
{
    SAMPLER = {};
}
```